# Mapping a document with partly-defined schema

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I'm writing a demo app using Spring & MongoDB as a database.

My main domain class looks like:

```
@Document
public class Person {

    @Id
    private String id;

    //Some other fields
    private DBObject additionalData;

}
```

The key is that additionalData is a subdocument with no schema specified, it is kind of user-defined JSON. But when I am parsing this json (using (DBObject) JSON.parse(value) expression), it is stored as a string in MongoDB, and I need it to be a nested document structure.

Searched for couple of hours, found no solution. Any ideas?

Comment: Could the class `implement` `java.util.Map<String, Object>` or maybe even `extend` `java.util.HashMap<String, Object>`?

Comment: Sorry for dumb question, but how can it help? Anyway, it can)

Comment: Some more code (the JSON parsing part) would be great as using `DBObject` is a valid mapping pattern, e.g. `new Person().setAdditionalData(new BasicDBObject("key", "value").append("x", "y"));`.

Comment: All JSON objects can be parsed into a Java `Map<String, Object>` objects. Check out Jackson and GSON.

Comment: Maybe I was not quite clear: JSON is parsed in additionalData field setter, not for the whole class.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl he is using the MongoDB internal JSON parser, which handles [BSON](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/) properly, including [ObjectId](http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/org/bson/types/ObjectId.html)s and [DBRef](http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/com/mongodb/DBRef.html)s. He may not be deserializing those, but at least using the internal parser makes it possible, while Jackson (and maybe GSON) don't (AFAIK).

Comment: Maybe this is a better answer to this question. [spring data mongodb mapping dynamic field](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47272787/2361959)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not really sure of the expected result of casting the result of

```
JSON.parse(value)
```

to [DBObject](http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/com/mongodb/DBObject.html), which is an interface, not a class.
Try casting the result to an implementation of DBObject [BasicDBObject](http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/com/mongodb/BasicDBObject.html) (or [BasicDBList](http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/com/mongodb/BasicDBList.html)), or a Map<String, Object> as mentioned in the comments (it is also an interface, but it does work).

If you're working with [Spring Data Rest](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-mongodb-data-rest/), you will probably not need to deserialize "manually", Spring will do it for you. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35847165/how-to-use-dynamic-schema-in-spring-data-with-mongodb/35921264#35921264) for a basic example of what to do.
Having data with no schema specified may not be the best idea around (mongodb saves you from doing it at the database level, but you should do it at the application level), but I use similar tricks in production, and you can somehow make it work.