# SpringMongo - discover document structure

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data

I have a customer's database that has a collection, in which the document fields can vary between each other. There are some constant fields I can rely on, but as for the rest - I have no way of narrowing the field list as the customer wants the solution to be dynamic.
My question is - can I somehow implement a generic mapping that would return, let's say, a map of document's fields using Spring Data?

edit:

Thanks for the tips. I've tried getting the generic Object (hoping I'd be able to convert it into a map) using the entity:

```
@Document(collection = "Data")
public class DataEntity {

    @Id
    private String id;

    private Object data;

    public Object getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(Object data) {
    this.data = data;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

}
```

but fetching the object by the ID using MongoRepository produces an object with data field set to null.
I'm using SpringBoot 1.3.1.RELEASE with spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb 1.3.1.RELEASE.

Comment: Look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35847165/5873923) for the answer to a similar question. Some implications are also discussed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36406195/5873923).

Comment: @Marc Thanks, I've just tried that out.
Any idea why this is not working for me? I'm getting a null value in data field. I've checked that the queried entry definettely has some additional fields.

Comment: As @titogeo mentionned in his comment, you need to put all your "dynamic" fields in the _properties_ (or whatever its name) field of your database object for the solution to work.

Comment: I see.
The problem is - I don't manage the DB structure, my application needs to perform some read-only operations on the database provided by a 3rd party.
Oh well, I'll try to hack something, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a Map for dynamic properties like below. Is this what you are looking for?

```
@Document(collection = "computers")
public class Computer {

  @Id
  private String id;

  @Field("name")
  private String name;

  //Other constant fields

  @Field("properties")
  private Map<String, Object> properties;

}
```

Comment: That's what I meant - but I don't have a constant field name like "properties" storing all of the dynamic fields. All the dynamic fields are on the main document level., eg:
`{"_id": ObjectId("123456789"), "name": "blablabla", "dynamic_field_1": "dynamic1", "dynamic_field_2": "dynamic2", etc... }`
 I've tried your solution but the properties field is being set tu null.

Comment: put all your dynamic fields as a Map.