# Storing a JSON schema in mongodb with spring

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb, jsonschema

I am new to Spring data and mongodb. I have a JSON object which represents a JSON Schema and I need to store that in mongodb using spring data. But the issue with JSON schema is the structure of JSON Schema is dynamic; for example below are two valid JSON schema with completely different structure.

```
{
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "name": {
            "type": "string",
            "minLength": 10
        },
        "age": {
            "type": "integer"
        }
    },
    "required": [
        "name",
        "age"
    ]
}
```

---

```
{
    "type": "array",
    "items": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
            "abc": {
                "type": "boolean"
            },
            "xyz": {
                "$ref": "#/definitions/"
            },
            "asd": {
                "type": "null"
            }
        },
        "required": [
            "abc",
            "xyz"
        ]
    }
}
```

How can I define a JAVA POJO Class so that I can map the above JSON with the defined class and store it in mongodb. Or is it possible to do CURD operation in spring without mapping it to a POJO class?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I would recommend using [MongoTemplate](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/MongoTemplate.html) and serialize and deserailize using [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson)/[Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson).

Mongo Template have CRUD methods which takes collection name and DBObject entity which is very similar to if you were to directly use mongo java driver.

So you will have json payload and using one of the mapper library to convert them into `Map`.

Something like

Deserialise

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(); 
TypeReference<HashMap<String,Object>> typeRef 
        = new TypeReference<HashMap<String,Object>>() {};
HashMap<String,Object> map = mapper.readValue(jsonpayload, typeRef);
```

DBObject

```
DBObject dbObject = new BasicDBObject(map);
```

MongoTemplate

```
mongoTemplate.save(dbObject, "collectionname");
```

You can do something similar for all other CRUD operations.

Answer (score 3):

Please find here the necessary code.

```
@lombok.Data
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Bounty {

  String type;
  Map<String, Object> items;
  Map<String, Object> properties;
  List<Object> required;
}
```

Here is my repository class

```
public interface BountyRepository extends MongoRepository<Bounty, String> {
}
```

And here is a controller snippet which u can use to try it out

```
@GetMapping("/insert/{number}")
    public void insert(@PathVariable int number){
        bountyRepository.save(getBounty(number));
    }


    public Bounty getBounty(int number){
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        String jsonString1 = "{\n" +
            "    \"type\": \"object\",\n" +
            "    \"properties\": {\n" +
            "        \"name\": {\n" +
            "            \"type\": \"string\",\n" +
            "            \"minLength\": 10\n" +
            "        },\n" +
            "        \"age\": {\n" +
            "            \"type\": \"integer\"\n" +
            "        }\n" +
            "    },\n" +
            "    \"required\": [\n" +
            "        \"name\",\n" +
            "        \"age\"\n" +
            "    ]\n" +
            "}";


        String jsonString2 = "{\n" +
            "    \"type\": \"array\",\n" +
            "    \"items\": {\n" +
            "        \"type\": \"object\",\n" +
            "        \"properties\": {\n" +
            "            \"abc\": {\n" +
            "                \"type\": \"boolean\"\n" +
            "            },\n" +
            "            \"xyz\": {\n" +
            "                \"$ref\": \"#/definitions/\"\n" +
            "            },\n" +
            "            \"asd\": {\n" +
            "                \"type\": \"null\"\n" +
            "            }\n" +
            "        },\n" +
            "        \"required\": [\n" +
            "            \"abc\",\n" +
            "            \"xyz\"\n" +
            "        ]\n" +
            "    }\n" +
            "}";

        try {
            Bounty bounty1 = objectMapper.readValue(jsonString1, Bounty.class);
            Bounty bounty2 = objectMapper.readValue(jsonString2, Bounty.class);


            if (number == 1) return bounty1;
            if (number == 2) return bounty2;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

This is how it looks like in Mongo after save.

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58da2390fde4f133178499fa"),
    "_class" : "pani.kiran.sumne.model.Bounty",
    "type" : "object",
    "properties" : {
        "name" : {
            "type" : "string",
            "minLength" : 10
        },
        "age" : {
            "type" : "integer"
        }
    },
    "required" : [ 
        "name", 
        "age"
    ]
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58da23adfde4f133178499fb"),
    "_class" : "pani.kiran.sumne.model.Bounty",
    "type" : "array",
    "items" : {
        "type" : "object",
        "properties" : {
            "abc" : {
                "type" : "boolean"
            },
            "xyz" : {
                "$ref" : "#/definitions/"
            },
            "asd" : {
                "type" : "null"
            }
        },
        "required" : [ 
            "abc", 
            "xyz"
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In my project I had a very dynamic structure of my models and I mapped them by using a `java.util.Map` object

this is how my mondo document model has been implemented:

```
@Document(collection = "e_form_data")
public class FormDataModel extends AbstractModel
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1733975205300782871L;
    @Field
    @Indexed(name = "e_form_id_idx")
    private String eFormId;
    @Field
    private Map<String, Object> eFormData;

    public FormDataModel()
    {
        super();
    }

    public FormDataModel(String id, String creatoDa, String modificatoDa, Date dataCreazione, Date dataModifica, String eFormId, Map<String, Object> eFormData)
    {
        super(id, creatoDa, modificatoDa, dataCreazione, dataModifica);
        this.eFormData = eFormData;
        this.eFormId = eFormId;
    }

    public FormDataModel(Map<String, Object> eFormData)
    {
        super();
        this.eFormData = eFormData;
    }

    public Map<String, Object> geteFormData()
    {
        return eFormData;
    }

    public void seteFormData(Map<String, Object> eFormData)
    {
        this.eFormData = eFormData;
    }

    public String geteFormId()
    {
        return eFormId;
    }

    public void seteFormId(String eFormId)
    {
        this.eFormId = eFormId;
    }

    public String getDataInserimento()
    {
        return Utils.formatDateTime(new DateTime(this.dataCreazione.getTime()), "dd/MM/yyyy");
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "FormDataModel [eFormId=" + eFormId + ", eFormData=" + eFormData + "]";
    }

}
```

By using this all works pretty good

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but still I am not sure how you will map that JSON structure to the Map you are suggesting?

Answer (score 1):

You can map embedded documents using `@DBref`

```
@Document(collection = "first")
public class First {

    @Id
    private String id;

    @DBRef
    private Properties properties;

    @Field
    private List<String> required;

    // constructor
    // getters and setter    
}

public class Properties {

    @Id
    private String id;

    @DBRef
    private Name name;

    @DBRef
    private Age age;

    // constructor
    // getters and setter   
}

public class Name { ... }
public class Age { ... }
```

http://www.baeldung.com/cascading-with-dbref-and-lifecycle-events-in-spring-data-mongodb

http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-mongo/docs/1.4.2.RELEASE/reference/html/mapping-chapter.html#mapping-usage-references

Or as Angelo Immediata suggested

```
@Document(collection = "first")
public class First {

    @Id
    private String id;

    @Field
    private Map<String, Object> properties;

    @Field
    private List<String> required;

    // constructor
    // getters and setter    
}
```

And you will need some custom read and write converters

http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-mongo/docs/1.4.2.RELEASE/reference/html/mapping-chapter.html#mapping-explicit-converters

Comment: The example that you gave, you defined classes named Name, Age etc. Here you are assuming that they are constant. If you see my second example the fields are different there; abc, xyz etc. My question is how to find a generic way that will dork for both the scenarios.

Comment: you need to put the dynamic data in java Object or  Map or com.mongodb.DBObject or com.mongodb.BasicDBObject  com.mongodb.BasicDBList. check this post  http://stackoverflow.com/a/35921264/1582089

Answer (score -1):

FWIW, MongoDB 3.6 introduced [JSON Schema Validation support](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/mongodb-36-json-schema-validation-expressive-query-syntax?jmp=adref) at the database level. You can read more on [MongoDB's blog](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/mongodb-36-json-schema-validation-expressive-query-syntax?jmp=adref). Hope that helps a bit!