# How should I define non-entity repositories with Spring Data MongoDB?

Tags: spring, mongodb

On my domain I have the usual entities (User, Company, etc) and also "entities" that doesn't change, I mean they are fixed values but stored on data base. My backend is Mongo so I make use of `MongoRepository`. I'm also using Spring Data Rest.

Let's say I have defined `Sector` as entity, which is nothing more than a String wrapped on a Java object.

So this is how I define the repository.

```
@RepositoryRestResource
public interface SectorRepo extends MongoRepository<Sector,String>{

}
```

The thing is that this seems to be inappropriate, as I should not define an object that only wraps an string and treat it as an entity, it isn't. The only purpose for Sector collection is to be loaded on a combo box, nothing more.
The problem gets serious when you have more and more of these non-entities objects.

How I should approach this situation so I can still use MongoRepository + Spring Data Rest?

Answer (score 2):

This is similar to couple of other questions. Please see my answers for both. Hope it helps

[Spring Data MongoDB eliminate POJO's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43098201/spring-data-mongodb-eliminate-pojos/43103165#43103165)

[Storing a JSON schema in mongodb with spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42973756/storing-a-json-schema-in-mongodb-with-spring/43065066#43065066)