# Spring Data MongoDB eliminate POJO's

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data

My system is a dynamic telemetry system.  We have hundreds of different spiders all sending telemetry back to the SpringBoot server, Everything is dynamic, driven by json files in Mongo, including the UI.  We don't build the UI, as opposed to individual teams can configure their own UI for their needs, all by editing json docs.

We have the majority of the UI running and i began the middleware piece.  We are using Spring Boot for the first time along with Spring Data Mongo with several MQ listeners for events.  The problem is Spring Data.  I started reading the docs on it and I realized the docs do not address using it without POJO's.  I have this wonderfully dynamic model that changes per user per minute if the telemetry spiders dictate, I couldn't shackle this to a POJO if I tried.  Is there a way to use Spring Data with a Map?

It seems from my experiments that the big issue is there is no way to tell the CRUD routines of the repository class what collection to query without a POJO.

Are my suspicions correct in that this won't work and am I better off ditching Spring Data and using the Mongo driver directly?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can do it without a pojo when using spring-data. The least you could do is this

```
public interface NoPojoRepository extends MongoRepository<DummyPojo, String> {
}
```

and create a dummy pojo with just id and a Map.

```
@Data
public class DummyPojo {
  @Id
  private String id;
  private Map<String, Object> value;
}
```

Since this value field is a map, you can store pretty much anything.

Comment: Yea, thats what i was thinking, but i refuse to change my model to accommodate a short sighted library.  Spent 40 years shackled to to RDBMS schemas only to shackle ourselves to POJO schema's.  Not going to do it.  I had a glimmer of hope that i can use the template directly with a bson document object, but looking at the way things are queried, that hope is fading too.  I can't waste any more time, I'm switching to the raw mongodb driver.

Comment: @scphantm Just a thought . I don't know if you have looked into mongotemplate which takes collection name and bson document object as parameters and you can perform all the actions.