# Using readEntity() to parse Json response with different tag names

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson, jersey-client

Parsing the json string to an object using readEntity() from jersey using jackson normally works fine but now I am using an API that returns an odd json structure that I don't know how to handle.

My model class Restaurant.java

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Restaurant {

    @JsonProperty("real_name")
    private String name;

    @JsonProperty("phone")
    private String phone;


    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }
}
```

And my Client method where I want to return a list of Restaurants.

```
  public List<Restaurant> getRestaurantsByZIP(String zip) {
        Response response = lunchgateClient.getRestaurants(zip, null, null, null);
        return response.readEntity(new GenericType<List<Restaurant>>() {
        });
    }
```

The json I am getting from the API

```
{
  "restaurants": {
    "key_0": {
      "id": "1172",
      "real_name": "Restaurant 1",
      "phone": "123456789",
      "email": "someEmail@email.com"
    },
    "key_1": {
      "id": "1173",
      "real_name": "Restaurant 2",
      "phone": "123456789",
      "email": "someEmail@email.com"
    }
  },
  "tags": "asian, eurpoean, cafe"
}
```

As you can see, the jsons consists of different Restaurants but instead of the restaurant entities beeing in a list, they are all a seperate object with the name key_0, key_1 and so on. How can I design my model that the readEntity() method works for this json without having "key_0" etc in my model as an attribute?

Comment: declare a Map with key as String and value as Object. Chack my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42973756/storing-a-json-schema-in-mongodb-with-spring/43065066#43065066

Comment: @pvpkiran This works but then I would have to change my Restaurant model to contain a Map<String,Restaurant>. I wuld like to avoid this and also I don't want to make a wrapper class only for the map.

Comment: You'd need to introduce custom converter, since your JSON body does not clearly fit into your POJO class.