# REST API consume dynamic JSON

Tags: java, json, rest, api, parsing

I have a REST API that will have a service that will receive a json that can change dynamically.

```
@POST
@Path("/my/service")
public Response saveData(@ApiParam GenericObject request);
```

I need to capture all the json content to store in the database. How can I do it? How I can build GenericObject to not throw a parser exception and capture all fields and child objects?

One dummy example of Json could be

```
{
"name":"John",
"age":30,
"cars":[ ... ] //Dynamic content
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Depending of your stack and actual need, you could maybe use Jackson annotations [@JsonAnyGetter](http://www.cowtowncoder.com/blog/archives/2011/07/entry_458.html) and @JsonAnySetter. Chech this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35847165/5873923) to see an example with Spring and MongoDB.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the below sample code, it works wonders for you. Initialise request headers.

```
 try {
 HttpHeaders requestHeaders = getRequestHeaders();
 HttpEntity<RequestDto> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(requestDto, requestHeaders);
 ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.postForEntity(baseUrl, requestEntity, 
 String.class);
 if (response != null && response.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.OK) {
 try {
 ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();                
 objectMapper.enable(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_EMPTY_STRING_AS_NULL_OBJECT);
 Map<?, ?> map = objectMapper.readValue(response.getBody(), Map.class);
 return new Response<ResponseDto>().buildSuccessResponse(map.toString());
 } 
catch (Exception e) {
 e.printStackTrace();
return new Response<ResponseDto>().buildErrorResponse("Failed to map response");
}}}
catch()
{
}
```