# spring mongo repository can't convert object woth field Array type

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, casting, spring-data

I have a mongo collection

```
{
 "_id": "someId",
 "data": [
         {
             "field1": "value1",
             "field2": "value2",
             "field3": "value3"
         },
         {
             "field1": "value1",
             "field2": "value2",
             "field3": "value3"
         },
     ]
}
```

and spring boot 2 application with repository

```
@Repository
public interface MyRepository extends MongoRepository<MyEntity, String> {
     MyEntity findByName(String myEntityName);
}
```

and entity

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class MyEntity {
 @Id
 private String name;
 private HashMap data;

 public MyEntity (String name, JsonNode data) {
     this.name = name;
     this.data = CommonUtils.convertToHashMap(data);
 }

 public void setData(JsonNode data) {
     this.data = CommonUtils.convertToHashMap(data);
 }
```

}

when i call  myRepository.findByName(name);
i take error :

```
Failed to convert from type [java.util.ArrayList<?>] to type [java.util.HashMap<?, ?>]
```

how fix this? in others documents i have identity fields, but not array, field type is object and it's ok. I know arrayList to hashMap looks strange, but i don't know how to edit entity or repository or mongo document. Please help.

P.S. sorry for bad English

Comment: Use `private List<HashMap> data;` instead.

Comment: i have array into Data field, your decision does not approach

Comment: Your `"data": [
         {
             "field1": "value1",
             "field2": "value2",
             "field3": "value3"
         },
         {
             "field1": "value1",
             "field2": "value2",
             "field3": "value3"
         },
     ]` in mongodb will only parse into `List` by default. Using a `HashMap` as an expectation, will ofcourse throw an exception

Comment: Maybe this helps to you:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35847165/how-to-use-dynamic-schema-in-spring-data-with-mongodb

Comment: Also see: [Data Mapping and Type Conversion](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/3.0.1.RELEASE/reference/html/#mapping-conversion) for Spring Data MongoDB.